# Precompile header and __AFXWIN_H__

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have created simple win32 console application:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    int num;
    cin >> num;

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine.

Then I'm trying to add library. I Have dll lib and .h files.

I have included my.h file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "my.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
```

`"my.h"` contains lines:

```
#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH
#endif
```

After compile I got error:

```
 include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH
```

But I have already included 'stdafx.h'. I have tested with both options of Use/Not use precompile headers - the same result.   Where is the problem?

Comment: stdafx.h must be included to .cpp file and not to .h file.

Comment: it is included in my application cpp file (first code block)

Comment: It is included to your h-file (second code block).

Comment: You should talk to the programmer that wrote "my.h", he wants you to write your code a certain way.  He probably insists that you #include the MFC headers in your stdafx.h file.  Pick up the phone and give him a call.

Answer (score 1):

Your `my.h` is using MFC (`__AFXWIN_H__` is defined by MFC headers) but your console program is not. You must use MFC in your program or rewrite your library to not use MFC.

Comment: But do I really need to call dll that was done using MFC only from C++ MFC project?

Comment: depends on how the dll is made. What do you export from it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not include external headers or stdafx.h in your headers.

Include all external headers in stdafx.h.

Include stdafx.h from every cpp file in your project.

This will build faster too as the external headers are processed once via PCH.